# JDK installation wizard not showing but installed anyway

Tags: windows-7, java, installation

I hope someone here can help me.

I'm one of a view java developers in my rather large company. So java is kind of neglected and I'm left alone managing my development environment.

I wanted to test the new JDK 9. Downloaded the installer. Double clicked the exe file and waited. Nothing happend except the blue buffering cirkle appearing. After  a while it disappeared. As if nothing happend. To my surprise the JDK and the jre were installed in the default way. I accidently found out hours later.

On my server (Windows 2012) the installation wizard works normal. I can choose the destination and so on. I tried an old jdk installation that worked priviously on my Windows 7 pc. The wizard didn't come up either.

I strongly believe that there is something going on with McAfee or windows policies. All these things are managed in a central IT department. I've already tried to find out by reaching out to them but nobody is interessted in helping me.

Does anyone here have the slightest idea whats going on on my pc or has anybody had this problem and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes up to my mind is that the installer is being forced to be run in silent mode. This can be forced by using a configuration file. Please check if such file exists in the following path:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg
```

The value of the environment variable `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` is typically `C:\ProgramData`.

If the configuration file contains a line setting `INSTALL_SILENT=Enable`, that setting will override the default and the Java installer will run in Silent mode.

To run the Java installer in the non-silent mode you can either edit the file to set `INSTALL_SILENT=Disable` or pass that parameter to the installer in the command line.

For further details and information check the Oracle tech documents [Installing With a Configuration File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#installing_with_config_file) and [Windows JRE Installer Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html)

Please confirm if this workaround fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the solution. I have a very strong idea which central installation routine this was set up with. We had an update for the oracle db client. At the same time the folder with these settings was created. I'm checking with central IT. Thank you so much. I would upvote the hell out of your answer if it was possible.